# Extend DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

A static constructor for class `SourceManager` goes through all modules/classes and discovers all classes that implement `ISource`.  It will instantiate each one of these and expose an `IEnumerable` of them as a static property called `IEnumerable<ISource> Sources`.  For simplicity `ISource` has two properties, `DataTable Table { get; }` and `string UniqueName { get; }`.  When instantiated each different `ISource` is responsible for populating its `Table` from SQL, MDX, etc.  For all the `ISource`'s I've written thus far, loading the `Table` with all `DataRow`s when instantiated has been sufficient.  However **I now have a situation where I'd like to load the `Table` with `DataRow`'s lazily, rather than all up front.  How do I do this?**  I will walk through an example.

`PermissionSource` implements `ISource`.  Its `Table` property, that has a `private set` is given a value of `new PermissionDataTable()`.  Its `UniqueName` is `"Permissions"`. As of right now there are no permissions loaded from the database into this `Table` property.

```
ISource permissionSource = SourceManager.Sources.
    Where(s => "Permission".Equals(s.UniqueName)).First();
```

Now we've obtained the `PermissionSource`, but through an interface.  Let's get a permission.

```
DataRow row = permissionSource.Table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().
    Where(r => r["PermissionName"].Equals("PermissionName")).First()
```

I've overriden the `Rows` property in `PermissionDataTable` so that the above, somehow, gets the value of the permissions associated with `"PermissionName"` in the database.  Other permissions are not loaded.

I don't have a choice in the permissions system and I don't have a choice to not use a `DataTable`.

**EDIT:**

In my example I would need to override the `Rows` property of `DataTable`.  `Rows`, though, is a [DataRowCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.aspx) which is `sealed`.  Thus there isn't much that can be done in terms of creating a minimal custom DataTable implementation like I want to do.

Comment: `DataTable` doesn't load anything from a database.  You should use Entity Framework.

Comment: Your question could be more clear. A `DataTable` is always a in-memory object and has no deferred execution or streaming capabilities. You might want to use a `DataReader` instead or do that all in database.

Comment: @SLaks I know it doesn't.  `ISource`'s are responsible for populating their `DataTable`'s with data from wherever they get their data from (I have  a SQL `ISource`, an MDX `ISource` and several others).  `DataTable` was chosen as a way to abstract the fact that the tablular data comes from different kinds of sources.

Comment: Concur with Tim S above; could you clarify what you mean by "...that intercepts *any calls like this*...like what? Just not fully understanding the issue.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared I have done something similar in the past. I kept my structures and provided extension methods that used reflection and built a datatable on the fly.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking how to write your own query provider.  That's...not trivial.

Comment: Where in your statement is the question mark?

Comment: @Jodrell Sorry I restated my question and forgot to make the question explicit in the restating.  If you need any clarification let me know.  I'm trying to remove as much unnecessary detail as I can.

Comment: It still isn't at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: So, when is your permissionSource.Table actually loaded in current implementation? Is there some command on permissionSource for loading?

Comment: @Nenad It was loaded whenever the static constructor for `SourceManager` was called (i.e. when `SourceManager.Sources` was called for the very first time.  I've since replaced it with a class called `SourceManager` that implements `ISourceManager`.  This class is bound to said interface via Ninject and is instantiated whenever the controller on the MVC website is instantiated.  I didn't know about IoC, before, and that seems to solve the problem with a little bit of change, elsewhere.  Knowing how to make a `DataTable` behave as if it's loaded, even though it isn't yet is still interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your restrictions in using a DataTable, but one thing I've done in the past when I needed to "refresh" the data in a DataTable or repopulate it using different criteria is to create a new class derived from DataTable that includes a reference to a DataAdapter with the connection and selection information originally used to fill the DataTable.

For example, the DataTable sub-class could look something like the `LazyDataTable` code below. Note that I have added several different methods of accessing the Rows. They might make more sense after taking a look at the `PermissionSource` and main `Program` code near the end of this post. *Also, please note that I have not included all of the details related to properly opening and closing database connections in every case. How you handle that will depend on your model for database access (e.g. connection pooling, shared connections etc).*

```
//using System.Data.Common;
public class LazyDataTable : DataTable {
    protected DbDataAdapter Adapter { get; set; }

    public LazyDataTable(DbDataAdapter a) {
        Adapter = a;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Save changes back to the database, using the DataAdapter
    /// </summary>
    public void Update() {
        Adapter.Update(this);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Fill this datatable using the SelectCommand in the DataAdapter
    /// The DB connection and query have already been set.
    /// </summary>
    public void Fill() {
        Adapter.Fill(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// read and return one row at a time, using IEnumerable syntax
    /// (this example does not actually add the row to this table, 
    /// but that can be done as well, if desired.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<DataRow> LazyReadRows() {
        using (var reader = OpenReader()) {
            //Get the schema from the reader and copy it to this table.
            var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
            var values = new object[schema.Columns.Count];
            while (reader.Read()) {
                reader.GetValues(values);
                var row = schema.NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = values;
                yield return row;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fill one row at a time, and return the new row.
    /// </summary>
    public DataRow ReadRow() {
        if (_reader == null || _reader.IsClosed) 
            _reader = OpenReader();
        //Get the schema from the reader and copy it to this table.
        if (this.Columns.Count == 0) 
            this.Columns.AddRange(_reader.GetSchemaTable().Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray());
        if (!_reader.Read()) {
            _reader.Dispose();
            return null;
        }
        var values = new object[_reader.FieldCount];
        _reader.GetValues(values);
        return this.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    private DbDataReader _reader = null;

    private DbDataReader OpenReader() {
        OpenConnect();
        return Adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    }

    private void OpenConnect() {
        var cn = Adapter.SelectCommand.Connection;
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            cn.Open();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Change a Parameter in the SelectCommand, to filter which rows to retrieve.
    /// </summary>
    public void SetSelectParam(string name, object value) {
        var selparams = Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters;
        selparams[name].Value = value;
    }
}
```

Then your `PermissionSource` would create a `LazyDataTable` and set the DataAdapter (including the connection and SELECT command) appropriately. It wouldn't fill the DataTable, but would instead return it empty, to be filled later, by the application code. So your `PermissionSource` might something like the code below. I've used `System.Data.OleDb` data objects as an example, but you would use whatever ADO providers you want.

```
interface ISource {
    public DataTable Table { get; }
    string UniqueName { get; }
}

public class PermissionSource : ISource {
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads a DataTable with all of the information to load it lazily.
    /// </summary>
    public DataTable Table { 
        get { 
            const string SELECT_CMD = "SELECT * FROM [Permissions] WHERE ([PermissionName] IS NULL OR [PermissionName]=@p1) AND [OtherProperty]=@p2";
            var conn = new OleDbConnection("...ConnectionString...");
            var selectCmd = new OleDbCommand(SELECT_CMD, conn);
            selectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", "PermissionName");
            selectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", 0);
            var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCmd);
            var builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter); //used to generate the UPDATE and DELETE commands...
            adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand(); //etc.
            //Do NOT fill the table here. Instead, let the caller fill it.
            return new LazyDataTable(adapter);
        }
    }
    public string UniqueName { get { return "Permission"; } }
}
```

Your main program code would use `PermissionSource` and `LazyDataTable` as follows:

```
    static class Program {
    void GetPermissions() {
        ISource permissionSource = SourceManager.Sources.
            Where(s => "Permission".Equals(s.UniqueName)).First();

        var table = permissionSource.Table as LazyDataTable;
        table.SetSelectParam("PermissionName", "Admin");

        //If you want to fill ALL rows in one step:
        table.Fill(); 

        // OR If you want to fill one row at a time, and add it to the table:
        DataRow row;
        while(null != (row = table.ReadRow())) {
            //do something with each individual row. Exit whenever desired.
            Console.WriteLine(row["PermissionName"]);
        }

        // OR If you prefer IEnumerable semantics:
        DataRow row = table.LazyReadRows().FirstOrDefault(someValue.Equals(row["columnname"]));

        //OR use foreach, etc. Rows are still ONLY read one at a time, each time IEnumerator.MoveNext() is called.
        foreach (var row in table.LazyReadRows())
            if (row["someColumn"] == "someValue")
                DoSomething(row["anothercolumn"]);
    }
}
```

You can certainly mix and match parts of the LazyDataTable shown here to achieve exactly what you want within your application constraints. It would of course be much better if you could switch to a different model of sharing data, but if you *MUST* return a DataTable from each Source, then at least you can return a more functional DataTable when necessary by subclassing it as I've demonstrated here. This allows you to pass back more information, which you can use to fill the table as you see fit.
I would still encourage you to look into LinqToSQL as well as possibly trying to switch to simply passing back a DbDataReader or some other object similar to the LazyDataTable I've shown here that will allow you to both customize the original query (e.g. by using the `SetSelectParam` method) and also to read the data in one row at a time.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably no use any more, but this might do it.

```
public interface ISource
{
    DataTable Table { get; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MySource : ISource
{
    private DataTable table;
    public DataTable Table
    {
        get
        {
            if (table == null)
                // Initialize your data.
                table = new System.Data.DataTable();
            return table;
        }
        private set
        {
            this.table = value;
        }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like LinqToSql, where each of your ISources could return a Table instead of a DataTable. 
This would allow you to use dynamic queries like you have given in the example, and load only the requested data, and only when needed.
I don't know if you will be able to find LinqToSql providers for all of your data sources. If that becomes a problem, you can try to use Entity Framework, as previously suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The following example adds a timestamp value to the DataTable through the ExtendedProperties property.

```
private void GetAndSetExtendedProperties(DataTable myTable){
 // Add an item to the collection.
 myTable.ExtendedProperties.Add("TimeStamp", DateTime.Now);
 // Print the item.
Console.WriteLine(myTable.ExtendedProperties["TimeStamp"]);
}
```