# Issue on inheriting from DataTable

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

```
public class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public DataTable MyData { get; set; }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //...do some processing on itself
        MyData = this;
    }
}
```

I created this MyDataTable class that inherits DataTable.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void ProcessData()
    {
        MyDataTable table = new MyDataTable();
        table.MyMethod();

        AcceptDataTable(table); //it won't accept the table parameter.
        AcceptDataTable(table.MyData); //it still won't accept the table parameter.
        AcceptDataTable((DataTable)table); //it still won't accept the table parameter.
    }

    public void AcceptDataTable(DataTable table)
    {
        Service1.SubmitData(table); //actually this is where it fails. It is a WCF Service's method that takes a DataTable as parameter. It works fine if I pass a DataTable, but not MyDataTable
    //There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:dt. The InnerException message was 'Type 'SubmitData' with data contract name MyDataTable
    }
}
```

Comment: List the error messages. This should work.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Your class is using both inheritance _and_ composition. `MyData = this` is a little strange.

Comment: You still need to list the error messages.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you extending a DataTable?  If you are looking to add methods, you should look into [Extension Methods](http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension).  I am pretty sure the the [DataTable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) does not have any virtual methods or properties that you could override, and memeber hiding does not work in [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152(v=vs.80).aspx).  [Check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162235/extend-datatable-in-c-sharp) for another view on someone that was trying to extend the DataTable as well.

Edited:

If you are also trying to pass your object through WCF, it must be marked [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx), but this causes some other funky issues, and could possibly be rejected if the base class has some sort of special serialization.  In that case marking your derived class as [Serializable] will kick out an error as well.

I would seriously consider the [Factory Pattern](http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory) from what you described.  That way you have your factory class that builds your table how you want it every time, but it is still a DataTable.

If you have any objects (not primitive) in your datatable, you must mark your WCF service to have the "KnownTypes(typeof(MyType))" so that it knows that there is something serialized inside the serialized datatable.

One final draw, you should avoid using datatables and datasets in WCF...

[Returning DataSets from WebServices is the Spawn of Satan and Represents All That Is Truly Evil in the World](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx)

[WCF Performance Using Datasets – Part 2](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/oshvartz/archive/2011/07/23/wcf-performance-using-datasets-part-2.aspx)

Comment: This should not make any difference (aside from not being able to call `MyMethod()`).

Comment: @HenkHolterman: You are right, I was more leaning towards the, "Don't Extend DataTable" approach.  Edited answer.

Comment: I updated my question. Actually it fails when I pass the MyDataTable parameter to a wcf service's method that takes a DataTable parameter.

Comment: I am extending it because this table will always have 4 specific columns. So instead of creating those columns on every instance I thought I can extend the DataTable and create the columns in the initialize method. And also to keep all the data transformation methods within itself

Comment: @gangt: I have changed my answer to respond to you.  WCF requires serializable objects, so you must mark your new object as Serializable for it to work (which the base DataTable is).  However, if that is all you are trying to do, use a Factory Pattern...

Comment: One of the reasons I had to use DataTable parameter in WCF Service is that the StoredProcedures have tabletype parameters. It is complicated to explain it here. It could have been done better but it's too late, I don't have a choice but to stick to passing datatable as parameter.

Comment: @gangt: Then take my other suggestion from my answer and use a Factory pattern, and extend DataTable using Extension methods where applicable.  At least try it, you'll like it...

Comment: I looked at the Factory Pattern, isn't that what I was doing by adding MyData property? The idea was to have a DataTable property within the MyDataTable class, but I guess the mistake I made was to assign MyData = this. I probably should do MyData.merge(this). I will try that.

Comment: @gangt: No, a factory pattern is where you have a class that has a static method(s) that create your object, in this case a DataTable, for you, and returns a new object (DataTable) setup how you want it to be.  The link I have shows a polymorphic example, but you could use the factory pattern to just make stuff and save on your repeated code.